# Dependency on ModalController in an Angular/Ionic module causes "Can't resolve all parameters" for the service

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, dependency-injection

I am creating a dynamic form module for Ionic 4.7.0 and Angular 5.0.3.
The module creates a DynamicFormComponent, but internally also uses the DynamicFormService. This service doesn't need to be available outside the module. The service depends on the Ionic ModalController to register modal popups. This dependency causes the following error:

`Can't resolve all parameters for DynamicFormComponent(?, [object Object])`.

If I remove the ModalController dependency from my service, the error disappears, but I need the ModalController to create popups in the different components of the module.

How can I fix this?

This is my dynamic-form.module.ts that is included in the imports of my AppModule:

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ReactiveFormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';

import { StringFieldComponent } from './fields/stringfield.component';
import { SelectFieldComponent } from './fields/selectfield.component';
import { NumberFieldComponent } from './fields/numberfield.component';

import { DynamicFormService } from './dynamic-form.service';
import { DynamicFormComponent } from './dynamic-form.component';
import { DynamicFieldDirective } from './dynamic-field.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    StringFieldComponent,
    SelectFieldComponent,
    NumberFieldComponent,
    DynamicFieldDirective,
    DynamicFormComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    DynamicFormService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    DynamicFormComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    StringFieldComponent,
    SelectFieldComponent,
    NumberFieldComponent,
  ]
})
export class DynamicFormModule {
}
```

This is an abbreviated version of the dynamic-form.component.ts which I think contains all relevant parts.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder }   from '@angular/forms';
import { FormConfig } from './models/form-config.interface';
import { DynamicFormService } from './dynamic-form.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() datasetSchema: object;
  @Input() formName: string;
  @Output() valueChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  payLoad: string;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  config: FormConfig;

  constructor(
    public dfs: DynamicFormService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.config = this.dfs.mapJSONSchema(this.datasetSchema)[this.formName];
    this.formGroup = this.createFormGroup();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if(this.valid){
      this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.value);
      this.valueChanged.emit(this);
      console.log("Form value", this.value);
    }
  }
  //...... Some stuff left out for brevity's sake
}
```

Here is the start of the DynamicFormService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormConfig } from './models/form-config.interface';
import { FieldConfig } from './models/field-config.interface';
import { DynamicSubFormComponent } from './dynamic-subform.component';
import { IntegerValidator } from './fields/validators';


@Injectable()
export class DynamicFormService {
  private modals = {};

  constructor(
    public modalCtrl: ModalController
  ) {
    console.log("Started dynamic form service");
  }
  //.... Again stuff left out for brevity's sake.
}
```

And to be safe, this is my app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EnviMo } from './app.component';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { DynamicFormModule } from '../dynamic-form/dynamic-form.module';

import { PageService } from '../providers/page-service/page-service';

import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ng-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EnviMo,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    DynamicFormModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(EnviMo)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    EnviMo,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    PageService,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your DynamicFormService itself have dependencies e.g. does it have parameters in it's constructor?

Comment: @Ryan sorry, forgot to include that piece of code. It's there now. To answer: yes it depends on the ionic ModalController

Comment: Make sure that the ModalController is provided somewhere before the DynamicFormService is used. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Hmm, the ModalController docs don't talk about needing to be provided anywhere, and putting it in the `providers[]` of my DynamicFormModule doesn't fix it, but removing the dependency alltogether does make the error go away. So I guess it has something to do with that but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It is a core angular-ionic Injectable that depends on the App to work. Somehow with the bootstrapping stuff, Ionic makes it available to the app, without the need to specify it anywhere using providers:[]. Some Ionic magic there. The bad part, this doesn't work for submodules since they don't have access to the app. I guess it's an ionic specific problem. I'll see if the Ionic form can indeed shed any light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is only a partial answer because it requires a bit of refactoring.
Apparently it is actual bad for to use the modalcontroller in a service, as the service is not a component and therefore not part of the DOM or component hierarchy or whatever it is called officially (please correct me). The ModalController on the other hand depends on the component hierarchy and specifically the App to be able to add the modal to the root component. The Ionic magic takes care of that during bootstrapping if I understand correctly. But since the DynamicFormService in my DynamicFormModule is instantiated before any bootstrapping happens, the service fails to be created. If it wouldn't be in the submodule but directly in the app, the bootstrapping happens first, and the service instantiation second. So no problem in that case.

BUT: the components (DynamicFormComponent and others) in my module only get created after the bootstrapping occurs. So they CAN use the ModalController.
So the solution was to move the modalCtrl.create calls to the components instead of putting them in the service, and injecting the ModalController in those components, not in the service.